# ERC721 how does tokenOfOwnerByIndex() list tokens owned by a user?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts, eip

Per [eip-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md), there's an optional "enumeration extension". So what I did was I called `balanceOf` to get the number of tokens owned by the account and called `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` in a loop to get each owned token ID.

```
for(var i = 0; i < balance.toNumber(); i++) {
  myERC721Token.tokenOfOwnerByIndex.call(web3.eth.accounts[0], i)
  .then((id) => { ... });       
}
```

As a result, it actually listed tokens owned by a user.

However, I am not sure how the code actually works because [`tokenOfOwnerByIndex` returns mapping variable `ownedTokens`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L81), but I've never assigned any value to `ownedTokens`! But how can it still return the tokens of an owner? FYI, I mint the token like below.

```
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol";

contract MyERC721Token is ERC721Token {

  function createNewToken(...) {
    _mint(msg.sender, index);
  }
}
```

If you take a look at openzeppelin's contract, `_mint` that I called here never assigns any value to `ownedTokens`. Can anyone see the relationships between the [contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721) that I can find out why `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` is working for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ERC721Token](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol) inherits from [ERC721BasicToken](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol).

When a new token is minted, [`_mint`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L167) is called from ERC721Token, which then calls `super._mint` which is the [`_mint`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol#L235) implementation from ERC721BasicToken.

`super._mint` calls `addTokenTo` from the top level implementation (ERC721Token).

[`addTokenTo`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L128) does additional logic to update the `ownedTokens` array in addition to calling `super.addTokenTo`, which again references the ERC721Basic token.

Thus, by using the `ERC721Token` you get this enumerable set of tokens for a user.

---

In general, you can think of this structure as one contract layer adding additional logic to another layer.

At the bottom you have ERC721BasicToken which by itself implements all of the functions needed for ERC721. Then you have ERC721Token which sits on top of ERC721BasicToken, and overwrites most of the functions with its own logic.

Cleverly, it ALSO includes the old logic using `super.functionName` syntax so that the old logic is run in addition to any new logic. Thus rather than *changing* the logic of the function, it **extends** the logic.

In this situation, the new logic does all the heavy lifting to make the tokens per owner enumerable.

Comment: Thanks I posted another question related to this. Please take a look. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70977/erc721token-super-mint-calls-addtokento-from-the-top-level-implementation