# ERC721Token super._mint calls addTokenTo from the top level implementation

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

Based on [Shawn's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70975/erc721-how-does-tokenofownerbyindex-list-tokens-owned-by-a-user),

> super._mint calls addTokenTo from the top level implementation (ERC721Token).

How does this work?

1. [`super._mint`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L168) calls [`_mint`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol#L235) from ERC721BasicToken
2. reads line [`addTokenTo`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol#L237)
3. calls top level [`addTokenTo`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L128) from ERC721Token
4. reads line [`super.addTokenTo(_to, _tokenId);`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L129)
5. executes [`addTokenTo`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol#L270) from ERC721BasicToken
6. comes back to `addTokenTo` in ERC721Token and executes the rest (`ownedTokens`)

Is this flow correct? and how come #2 doesn't call `addTokenTo` in ERC721BasicToken and calls top level `addTokenTo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solidity compiler does some "magic" when you include multiple files and do contract inheritance as is done in the ERC721 token contract. Ultimately it flattens the contract files into a single file and treats the inheritance and overridden functions in a deterministic way:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#inheritance

> All function calls are virtual, which means that the most derived function is called, except when the contract name is explicitly given.
>
> When a contract inherits from multiple contracts, only a single contract is created on the blockchain, and the code from all the base contracts is copied into the created contract.

Here is what ["most derived"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241637/what-does-the-most-derived-object-mean) means; take a look at the example from the docs about `Base1` and `Base2`.

---

Ultimately, the top level contract's function implementation will ALWAYS be the one called unless specified explicitly to be different.

Imagine this was not the case; it would be impossible to create wrapper contracts like this since a base contract would have no context that it is being wrapped, and thus would have no idea that it would need to call the "wrapped" version of a function rather than its own.

Thus we always call the "most derived" version of a function. Since we know the outer most contract always has context of the contracts it wraps, this pattern allows for exactly these scenarios where we are looking to extend the functionality of some base contract to do something more.

Comment: Thanks your explanation is better than the docs. Docs' `A call to Final.kill() will call Base2.kill as the most derived override` doesn't make sense to me because both base1,2 inherits the same class. So not sure why `Final.kill()` will call `Base2.kill` first rather than calling `Base1.kill`

Comment: Anyways, based on your answer I understood this concept in the following way:
 
1. all contracts (including inherited ones) are flattened into a single file
2. the top level contract's function (identical func name & params) is always called
3. so in our case, line `addTokenTo` in `_mint` from ERC721BasicToken will be directed back to `addTokenTo` in ERC721Token since their names are identical and sit at the top level.

Am I correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me.